# Frequency algorithm of element inside array in time O(n)

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I wanted to ask if there is an algorithm that can find, in an array of length `n`, if there is an array element with a certain frequency percentage (10%, 20% etc...) in linear time.

Selection sort is `O(n^2)` and the majority algorithm even if `O(n)` can only find if the number is repeated at least n/2 times.

Comment: just iterate over the array, count occurences and divide by the number of elements?

Comment: In O(n)? If i count the occurrences of every element I have to iterate over the array n times so complexity will be n^2, i thought about something like counting sort but the interval of numbers  is not known

Comment: if you apply count sort then only one time iteration will be done means complexity is O(n) and getting count of that number is in O(1)

Comment: Are there restrictions on space usage? You can simply create a dictionary mapping elements to count. This takes an additional O(n) space for an algorithm that runs in O(n) time.

Comment: At the very beginning i thought to use a modified radix/counting sort with dictionary, 1 check of the array to find the max value, and using a dictionary by the number of digits of that number, but the answer of my teacher was: radix sort computation time depends on the mean value of the digits of the array elements, and if that value is bigger than n the complexity is even worse than comparison sorting algorytms like qs or ms...
By the way, no space restrictions, only that damn linear time complexity

Comment: Why do a radix sort at all? Just create a dictionary. If that's a bit more spacious than necessary, who cares? Create dict, iterate list, increase counters, iterate dict to find frequent numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You are making this out to be a lot harder than it really is, assuming you don't have space limits.

The idea is to iterate the array and save the count of each element while doing so. Dictionary (or equivalent structure) lookup is O(1) so it's not a problem.
Then just iterate over the dictionary and see what elements have the required frequency.

Python pseudocode:

```python
for elem in array:
    count[elem] = count.get(elem, 0) + 1
for elem, elem_count in count.items():
    if 0.20 <= float(elem_count) / len(array) <= 0.25:
        print "{} has a frequency between 20% and 25%".format(elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

int counter = 0; (no influence on run time in this code line).
Iterate the arry using loop (for,while,whatever). For each element:
  - if(element == what_you_search)
    counter++;

//This if statment is o(1) in each iteration, there were n interation so in the overall it is
//o(n) for the whole loop.
int percentage = counter / (array.len()); //It is being done in o(1).

o(1) + o(n) + o(1) = o(n)

Comment: Please be careful with notation: o(n) is not the same as O(n).

Comment: Ohh misunderstood question.... in that case there is a diffent algorithm. don't remmember it's name.

Comment: I will write here pseudo code:
SortedArray = Array accepted from any O(n) sorted array algorithm.  
(I know there are few like this just choose one).  
CheckElement = sortedArray[0]  
Counter = 1  
for(int i = 1; i< array.len ; i++){  
  if(SortedArray[i] == CheckElement)  
     Counter++;  
   else{  
     if counter indicates elements shows 10% or whatever  
       return true;  
      else  
       CheckElement = SortedArray[i];  
   }  
}

Comment: General idea is sorting array and then check how many equal values are repetead until get an index having a new element value, then see if counter of elements is ok for your criteria